# Paypal Rest API and Permissions API from classic

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-permissions

Im trying to implement paypal on a website, where I want to give my site-users the ability to add paypal as an payment option for there web shops. So I'm using Laravel, and I found this one, http://jslim.net/blog/2014/09/19/integrate-paypal-sdk-into-laravel-4/ and do pretty much like that. 
So my question is, is it possible to combine the Permissions API from the Classic API and using the Rest API for my shop? And then could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Currently adding PayPal REST API and Classic API SDKs are causing namespacing conflict issues, as to prevent breaking changes in REST API. The work is under way to release 1.x version of REST APIs that would allow you to work with both rest and classic APIs together.

Comment: Ok, do you have any good tutorial or such that would explain how to use classic api and permissions and express checkout?

Comment: I have the same question as @AndreasGrandin … any news?

Comment: When you install any classic SDK, you will be getting samples downloaded along with it. As for e.g. : https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php#running-the-sample

You should be able to run the samples, and copy code for getting your classic APIs working.